# I need to a function to optimize the deletion of a message thread based on the last message create in the thread and a given date

Tags: java, spring, database, mongodb

i want an algorithm that delete messages in a thread based on the last message created in the thread

that is if the last message was created after a time passed as parameter, delete all the messages in the thread

this is the message model

```
@Getter
@Setter
@FieldNameConstants
@Document(collection = "messages")
public class Message {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private int messageTypeDictionaryValueId;
    private String messageTypeDictionaryValueName;
    private Long sender;
    private String messageHeader;
    private String messageText;
    private String messageRoot;
    private String pageReference;
    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
}
```

a thread start with a message with no root and then all the messages that has root to the original message are part of the thread

As you can see i am using mongo

Originally i had this

```
messageRepository.findAllByCreatedAtBefore(leastValidDate);
```

but the problem is that in a message thread this can delete a root when the responses are still valid and visible, which is not good

What i want is that if even one of the responses has not passed the limitation then we should keep the whole thread, even if the root message is too old.

For simplicity purpose you keep the thread to be only two level that is a root and many messages so that a message that has a root message cannot be the root message of another message.

Originally i had this

messageRepository.findAllByCreatedAtBefore(leastValidDate);